# How to migrate data after upgrading from Azure mobile service to app service?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

**Scenario:** I have a migrated Azure mobile service, with data tables, that I would like to upgrade to an Azure app service. I have followed  [this upgrade documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services#a-nameoverviewabasic-upgrade-overview). I have copied the connection string and the application name as described in the documentation.

**Expectations:** What I would like to see are the same data tables from my mobile service in my new app service's Easy Tables. I would also like these to map to the same tables in the same database.

**Problem:** The problem is however that I don't see the data tables from my mobile service in my new app service (in Easy Tables).

**More info:** I have also tried to recreate the tables in the new app service. But if I create a new table in easy tables it creates a new table in the database, probably because the created table name does not match the schema from my mobile service? My mobile service uses the following schema: `[database name].[mobileservice name].[table name]`. The app service uses this schema: `[database name].[table name]`.

**So my question is:** does anybody know how to migrate the data tables from a migrated mobile service to an app service?

Answer (score 0):

> Expectations: What I would like to see are the same data tables from my mobile service in my new app service's Easy Tables. I would also like these to map to the same tables in the same database.

AFAIK, when using **Easy Tables**, you could add your new table or existing table with the same name, then it would help you to build the node.js backend for your added tables automatically.

**Note:**

> Table names can contain only letters, numbers, and underscores. The name must begin with a letter or a underscore character.

You could leverage "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS > App Service Editor (Preview)" of your mobile app service for checking your backend as follows:

[image]

> So my question is: does anybody know how to migrate the data tables from a migrated mobile service to an app service?

According to the upgrade documentation you provided, I assumed that you are developing the C# backend, you just need to refer to [Updating the server project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services#updating-the-server-project), then deploy your modified project to your new app service.

Moreover, I would recommend that you could navigate to "DEPLOYMENT > Quickstart" of your app service, then download the C# backend project to be familiar with the new server project before you updating your mobile services backend project. Additionally, I would prefer creating a new mobile app project, then create the table controllers and migrate the logical code from your mobile service project. For more details about creating table controllers, you could refer to adrian hall's book [Implementing Table Controllers](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but we decided not to upgrade to App Services anymore. The reason is because we don't want to have to recreate our entire backend every time Microsoft decides to rewrite their stuff in an non backwards compatible way. We need something more reliable and future proof.